# Unable to set geometry in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I get an error with `setGeometry` in a very simple program in Qt5.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLabel* m_photo = new QLabel;
    m_photo->setPixmap(QPixmap("test.jpg"));
    m_photo->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

> Error: setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 6x16+640+300 on
>   QWidgetWindow/'QLabelClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  160x16+640+300
>   (frame: 9, 38, 9, 9, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0,
>   maximum size: 16777215x16777215).

I see [Qt adding custom widget to a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494839/qt-adding-custom-widget-to-a-layout), but I did not understand the comment. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you get this error because you don't use `setGeometry()`, you should set geometry yourself. Try this:

```
m_photo->setGeometry(200,200,200,200);
```

Better way: label should have same size as picture. To do this you can use `QPixmap` method `width()` and `height`

```
    QLabel* m_photo = new QLabel;
    QPixmap px("G:/2/qt.jpg");
    m_photo->setPixmap(px);
    m_photo->setGeometry(200,200,px.width(),px.height());
    m_photo->show();
```

Edit.

I understood why you get this error. It is very simple, your picture doesn't load! Why? Very simple too: probably your picture(`test.jpg`) was putted near exe file, but Qt doesn't see this file(because Qt use another build directory)

Solution: put `test.jpg` in correct directory or set pixmap full path(ad I do `"G:/2/test.jpg"` for example). Also use this code: check is your picture load successfully.

```
    QLabel* m_photo = new QLabel;
    QPixmap px("G:/2/qt.jpg");
    if(!px.isNull())
    {
    m_photo->setPixmap(px);
    m_photo->show();
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "Cannot find picture";
```

Is it work now?

Comment: The problem it is not due to not loading the image. It happens when the application minimum resolution is larger than display resolution.
In my case was happening when display image on graphicsviewer, the graphicsviewer needed to get some extra space to get handlers of scrollbar when displaying large image and this caused the problem.