# OpenCV & Qt - SetGeometry-Error

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I looked through the following links but could not find a solution to my problem:

[Qt setGeometry: Unable to set geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230975/qt-setgeometry-unable-to-set-geometry)

[Unable to set geometry in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537089/unable-to-set-geometry-in-qt)

https://forum.qt.io/topic/38304/setgeometry-unable-to-set-geometry

The following code produces a the error. While debugging with Visual Studio the image is still being displayed. But when using the executable directly the program crashes.

> QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 374x133+2679+423
>   on QWidgetWindow/'TestWindowWindow'. Resulting geometry: 
>   376x141+2679+423 (frame: 8, 31, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   minimum size: 374x133, maximum size: 374x133).

My code looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout << "Test-Console for OpenCV" << endl;

  string path = "C:/Data/01_Daten/tiger.bmp";
  cv::Mat image = cv::imread(path, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

  if (image.empty())
  {
    cout << "Failed to read image" << endl;
    getchar();
    return 1;
  }

  cv::namedWindow("TestWindow", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cv::imshow("TestWindow", image);

  cout << "Press any key to exit..." << endl;

  cv::waitKey(-1);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm using Visual Stuido 2013, OpenCV 3.3.0, QT 5.9.2
OpenCV is compiled with WithQT.

Comment: Your code seems to have nothing to do with Qt. OpenCV has its own GUI toolkit. So that error regarding `QWindowsWindow::setGeometry` is probably caused by somewhere else.

Comment: As far as I understood OpenCV compiled with Qt, it uses Qt instead of the "normal" GUI if Qt is enabled during the compilation. As the code I want to write uses Qt I have to enable it. The code above represents a minimal-working-example which produces the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soltuion to my problem was to rebuild OpenCV with not only the Option *WithQT* but also *WithOpenGL* selected.

I'm not sure wether this is the only way to fix the problem as I assume, that the QT-Module should even work without the OpenGL-Part, but it helped me.